# how to create a new uri which needs to contain a string

Tags: c#, string, uri

I'm using a web browser and the uri that the web browser displays is constantly changing.

The exact location of the uri is not known as users will install the program containing the files to their Program Files folder.

If I use

```
    directoryString += Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

It will return C://Program Files (x86) as I want it to but how do I merge this into a uri?

So I basically want

```
    this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("file://" + directoryString + "myFolder/StoryBox/desert.html");
```

So if it ran it would be file://C:/Program Files (x86)/myFolder/StoryBox/desert.html);

P.S. I need it with the string incase the OS is 32 bit and it wont have the Program Files (x86) folder and I'm not writing C:/ incase they have a different drive name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have the answer in your question. Let me know if I'm missing something.

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
var path = Path.Combine(folder, "myFolder/StoryBox/desert.html");
var uri = new Uri("file:" + path);
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly. Thank you so much. Makes my life a lot easier :D!